# Edit workbook in desktop, developer insert not available

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file in a sharepoint. To edit I open in desktop.
From here I want to insert a button, to link to a macro, then save and have the button/macro be saved then upload back to the sharepoint.

Why is my Insert button disabled?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of file format did the Workbook?

Comment: Is it disabled when you reopen it on desktop, or just when viewed in sharepoint?

Comment: @Lee, .xlsb .  It is disabled only on desktop, the developer tab isnt available on sharepoint.